# PDO bindparam (?) in WHERE clause block DATATABLE paging

Tags: sql, pdo, datatable, datatables

I'm using Datatable along with PDO, and i've a probleme with this where clause :

```
$orderBy=" ORDER BY dayofweek>=1 DESC, dayofweek ASC, starttime ASC ";

$sql="SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS op.*
    FROM ophours op
    WHERE op.memberid IN (?)
    $orderBy
    LIMIT ?,? ; ";
$res=pdoquery($sql, array($shopids, (int)$_GET['iDisplayS'], (int)$_GET['iDisplayL']));
```

if I remove the line `WHERE op.memberid IN (?)` along with removing the $shopids from the binded params the paging work again.
If I don't, I can only get the fist page of results. If I try to load more results then I get an error 500.
I'm almost sure the problem come from the `WHERE X IN (?)`

Are you aware of a way to replace this line ? Putting directly the $shopids instead of the (?) won't work, I must bind it.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

for the in clause with array you should pass  ? as many elements you have in array

```
  $in  = str_repeat('?,', count($shopids) - 1) . '?';
  $sql="SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS op.*
    FROM ophours op
    WHERE op.memberid IN ($in)
    $orderBy
    LIMIT ?,? ; ";
  $stm = $db->prepare($sql);
  $stm->execute($arr,(int)$_GET['iDisplayS'], (int)$_GET['iDisplayL']);
  $res = $stm->fetchAll();
```

Comment: First thank you for your answer. It keep working this way, but going further on the pagination just doesn't work. If I have 12 data to show, and print 10 per page, going on the second page to print 2 data give me an error. Same if I have 26 data, the third page keep sending me error 500.